# Slow integration of system ODE under specific conditions in adsorption problem

Tags: chemical-engineering, modeling, matlab, mass-transfer

I am trying to solve the system of ODEs below. I am applying the finite differences to z, so I get a system of ODE that I can solve with a solver like ode45.

[image: ODE system]

The problem is that under the conditions that interest me integration is too slow (time step is very small) and I get no result. I would like to know what is the underlying problem and if there is any way to solve it. I have tried:

- using different solvers (tried all of them)
- using dimensionless variables
- using the pdepe function of Matlab to solve the PDE system directly without applying finite differences myself. Same problem occurs.

**Full code (using the parameters that do not work)**

```
function transport_model()
global parameter L Di epsb Q Cfeed K tfinal npz npt F ui h

parameter = [0.044511*432.75 432.75];    % isotherm parameters
L = 0.4;            % m, column length
epsb = 0.367;       % column bulk porosity
ui = 4e4;        % m/s, velocity
Cfeed = 200;     % feed concentration
K = 0.0782          % s-1, mass transfer coefficient
tfinal = 400;      % min, final time for calculation
npz = 50;           % number of discretization points in z
npt = 20;

F = (1-epsb)/epsb;
tspan = 0:tfinal/(npt-1):tfinal;
y0 = zeros(2*npz,1);
h = L/(npz-1);

sol = ode15s(@sedo, tspan, y0);
t = sol.x;
C1 = sol.y(1:npz,:);
q1 = sol.y((npz+1):end,:);

plot(t, C1(end,:))
xlim([0 tfinal])
ylim([0 Cfeed])



function DyDt = sedo(t,y)
global Cfeed K  npz F ui h

N = npz;
y(1) = Cfeed;
DyDt = zeros(2*N,1);

% Forward finite differences
DyDt(1) = -ui * 1/(2*h)*(-y(3)+4*y(2)-3*y(1)) - F * K * (y(1) - ilangmuir(y(N+1)));
DyDt(N+1) = K * (y(1) - ilangmuir(y(N+1)));

% Central finite differences
for i=2:N-1
    DyDt(i) = -ui * 1/(2*h)*(y(i+1)-y(i-1)) - F * K * (y(i) - ilangmuir(y(N+i)));
    DyDt(N+i) = K * (y(i) - ilangmuir(y(N+i)));
end

% Backward finite differences
DyDt(N) = -ui * 1/(2*h)*(3*y(N)-4*y(N-1)+y(N-2)) - F * K * (y(N) - ilangmuir(y(N+N)));
DyDt(2*N) = K * (y(N) - ilangmuir(y(N+N)));



function c = ilangmuir(q)
% langmuir solved for c
global parameter

a = parameter(1);
b = parameter(2);

c = q /(a - b * q);
```

However, if I try to model a different case (different conditions) I get the correct response. So I am assuming this is a numerical problem caused by the conditions I am trying to model and not an error in the model. For instance, if I use the conditions below I get the correct response.

```
parameter = [0.044511*432.75 432.75];    % isotherm parameters
L = 0.4;            % m, column length
epsb = 0.367;       % column bulk porosity
ui = 0.0056;        % m/s, velocity
Cfeed = 0.0025;     % feed concentration
K = 0.0782          % s-1, mass transfer coefficient
tfinal = 4000;      % min, final time for calculation
npz = 50;           % number of discretization points in z
npt = 20;
```

[image]